# Not able to retrieve element from Hazelcast's Map if using custom object as a key

Tags: hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

I am using Hazelast Map and trying to store Objects against key which is object of my custom class i.e. `HMapKey`. Here is snippet of `HMapKey` class.

```
public class HMapKey implements Serializable{
    private String keyCode;
    private long time;

    public HMapKey(String keyCode, long time) {
      this.keyCode = keyCode;
      this.time = time;
    }
    public String getKeyCode() {
        return keyCode;
    }
    public void setKeyCode(String keyCode) {
        this.keyCode = keyCode;
    }
    public long getTime() {
        return time;
    }
    public void setTime(long time) {
        this.time = time;
    }
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((keyCode == null) ? 0 : keyCode.hashCode());
        return result;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        HMapKey other = (HMapKey) obj;
        if (keyCode == null) {
            if (other.keyCode != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!keyCode.equals(other.keyCode))
            return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

As you can see in above code, I have used only `keyCode` in equals() method to compare two objects. So no matter what value is there for `time` variable.
But when I use this object as key in Hazelcast's Map, and try to retrieve it, I think Hazelcast checking each and every variable of key class, because of this, even if I have same `keyCode` variable value and different `time` variable, Hazelcast returning me as `NULL`. Is there any configuration to tell Hazelcast not to go for all variable checking and use existing `equals()` method only?

Here is code how I am trying to retrieve data from map

```
HazelcastInstance instance = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance();
private static ConcurrentMap<HMapKey, String>   testMap = instance.getMap("TEST_MAP");
testMap.put(new HMapKey("code1",123), "This is Code 1");
System.out.println(testMap.get(new HMapKey("code1",0)));
```

Means, while insertion, I have created key object like `new HMapKey("code1",123)` but while retrieving it, I am creating new object as `new HMapKey("code1",0)` and this is returning me as null value. Whereas if I try with `new HMapKey("code1",123)` it's working fine.

Comment: Can you also post the code where you are trying to retrieve from the map ?

Comment: Updated my Question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that by declaring variable `time` as `transient`. But note that it will lead to collisions and give random results. Your put operation would overwrite the previous value even though it's properties are different.

```
HazelcastInstance instance = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance();
IMap<HMapKey, String> testMap = instance.getMap("TEST_MAP");

testMap.put(new HMapKey("code1",123), "This is Code 1");

System.out.println("HMapKey with time=0: " + testMap.get(new HMapKey("code1",0)));
System.out.println("HMapKey with time=123: " + testMap.get(new HMapKey("code1",123)));


testMap.put(new HMapKey("code1",456), "This is Code 2");
System.out.println("HMapKey with time=123: " + testMap.get(new HMapKey("code1",123)));
```

Output would be:

```
HMapKey with time=0: This is Code 1
HMapKey with time=123: This is Code 1
HMapKey with time=123: This is Code 2
```

Comment: Thanks.. It works for me. But this is the only way to do this? As I want to use that `time` variable on cluster. But that should not be part of validating key.

Comment: I believe so. You can perhaps explore the Serialization topic to check how it converts the key. If you want to use the `time` variable then better to include it in your hashcode/equals implementations.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I don't know what you're trying to do when you say "I try to retrieve it".

If you use your key as in the get method everything works fine:

```
@Test
public void test() {
    HazelcastInstance hz = createHazelcastInstance();

    IMap<HMapKey, Integer> map = hz.getMap("aaa");
    HMapKey key = new HMapKey();
    key.keyCode = "code1";
    key.time = 123;

    HMapKey key2 = new HMapKey();
    key2.keyCode = "code2";
    key2.time = 246;

    map.put(key, 1);
    map.put(key2, 2);

    int value = map.get(key);
    assertEquals(value, 1);
}
```

If you want to retrieve a value basing on the whole key value the HMapKey needs to implement `Comparable`.

Then you can query like this:

`map.values(Predicates.equal("__key", yourHKMapKeyInstance));`

Comment: @tom, it's not working even if you implement `Comparable`

Answer (score 1):

Hazelcast does not deserialize the keys / values and executes `equals` or `hashCode` methods but compares the serialized objects by their corresponding bytestream. If you're searching for one or more properties, please see the answer from Tom https://stackoverflow.com/a/41238649/917336

Comment: If I want to validate key object using single element from class instead all as you mentioned like bytestream, is there any way? I have try with Tom's answer, but didn't able to achieve.

Comment: You cannot validate but query and see if the result is what you expected.