# Hazelcast IMap sometime returns null value object even if it is present in map

Tags: java, hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

I have one map in Hazelcast with key and values are like `IMap`. Now I have two nodes with me. Problem is when I am trying to get value object from Hazelcast map, some time it returns me `NULL` and very next call, it works fine. As this is working fine for some time, I think there is no issue with code. Here I am sharing my map configurations from `hazelcast.xml` file.

```
<map name="MY_HAZELCAST_MAP">
       <in-memory-format>OBJECT</in-memory-format>
       <backup-count>1</backup-count>
       <async-backup-count>0</async-backup-count>
       <time-to-live-seconds>1000</time-to-live-seconds>
       <eviction-percentage>25</eviction-percentage>
       <max-size policy="PER_NODE">3000</max-size>
       <cache-deserialized-values>ALWAYS</cache-deserialized-values>
       <merge-policy>com.hazelcast.map.merge.PassThroughMergePolicy</merge-policy>
</map>
```

Please let me know if I am configuring something wrong. Using `hazelcast-all-3.7.3.jar`.

Here is hazelcast.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<hazelcast xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config hazelcast-config-3.6.xsd"
           xmlns="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <properties>
        <property name="instance.name">MY_INSTANCE</property>
        <property name="hazelcast.logging.type">log4j</property>
    </properties>
    <group>
        <name>dev1</name>
        <password>dev-pass</password>
    </group>
    <management-center enabled="false">http://localhost:8080/mancenter</management-center>
    <network>
        <port auto-increment="false" port-count="100">51253</port>
        <outbound-ports>
            <ports>0</ports>
        </outbound-ports>
        <join>
            <multicast enabled="false"/>
            <tcp-ip enabled="true">
                <member-list>
                    <member>192.168.1.87:51253</member>
                </member-list>
            </tcp-ip>
            <discovery-strategies>
            </discovery-strategies>
        </join>
        <ssl enabled="false"/>
        <socket-interceptor enabled="false"/>
        <symmetric-encryption enabled="false">
            <algorithm>PBEWithMD5AndDES</algorithm>
            <salt>thesalt</salt>
            <password>thepass</password>
            <iteration-count>19</iteration-count>
        </symmetric-encryption>
    </network>
    <partition-group enabled="false"/>
    <executor-service name="default">
        <pool-size>16</pool-size>
        <queue-capacity>0</queue-capacity>
    </executor-service>
    <queue name="default">
        <max-size>0</max-size>
        <backup-count>1</backup-count>
        <async-backup-count>0</async-backup-count>
        <empty-queue-ttl>-1</empty-queue-ttl>
    </queue>
    <map name="MY_HAZELCAST_MAP">
           <in-memory-format>OBJECT</in-memory-format>
           <backup-count>1</backup-count>
           <async-backup-count>0</async-backup-count>
           <time-to-live-seconds>1000</time-to-live-seconds>
           <eviction-percentage>25</eviction-percentage>
           <max-size policy="PER_NODE">3000</max-size>
           <cache-deserialized-values>ALWAYS</cache-deserialized-values>
           <merge-policy>com.hazelcast.map.merge.PassThroughMergePolicy</merge-policy>
    </map>
    <map name="default">
        <in-memory-format>BINARY</in-memory-format>
        <backup-count>1</backup-count>
        <async-backup-count>0</async-backup-count>
        <time-to-live-seconds>0</time-to-live-seconds>
        <max-idle-seconds>0</max-idle-seconds>
        <eviction-policy>NONE</eviction-policy>
        <max-size policy="PER_NODE">0</max-size>
        <eviction-percentage>25</eviction-percentage>
        <min-eviction-check-millis>100</min-eviction-check-millis>
        <merge-policy>com.hazelcast.map.merge.PutIfAbsentMapMergePolicy</merge-policy>
        <cache-deserialized-values>INDEX-ONLY</cache-deserialized-values>
    </map>

    <multimap name="default">
        <backup-count>1</backup-count>
        <value-collection-type>SET</value-collection-type>
    </multimap>

    <list name="default">
        <backup-count>1</backup-count>
    </list>

    <set name="default">
        <backup-count>1</backup-count>
    </set>

    <jobtracker name="default">
        <max-thread-size>0</max-thread-size>
        <queue-size>0</queue-size>
        <retry-count>0</retry-count>
        <chunk-size>1000</chunk-size>
        <communicate-stats>true</communicate-stats>
        <topology-changed-strategy>CANCEL_RUNNING_OPERATION</topology-changed-strategy>
    </jobtracker>

    <semaphore name="default">
        <initial-permits>0</initial-permits>
        <backup-count>1</backup-count>
        <async-backup-count>0</async-backup-count>
    </semaphore>

    <reliable-topic name="default">
        <read-batch-size>10</read-batch-size>
        <topic-overload-policy>BLOCK</topic-overload-policy>
        <statistics-enabled>true</statistics-enabled>
    </reliable-topic>

    <ringbuffer name="default">
        <capacity>10000</capacity>
        <backup-count>1</backup-count>
        <async-backup-count>0</async-backup-count>
        <time-to-live-seconds>30</time-to-live-seconds>
        <in-memory-format>BINARY</in-memory-format>
    </ringbuffer>

    <serialization>
        <portable-version>0</portable-version>
    </serialization>
    <services enable-defaults="true"/>
    <lite-member enabled="false"/>
</hazelcast>
```

For sample code please refer [Not able to retrieve element from Hazelcast's Map if using custom object as a key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41238403/not-able-to-retrieve-element-from-hazelcasts-map-if-using-custom-object-as-a-ke) which I have posted. My key contains time variable which can be changed. As Mr. Desai mentioned about Hazelcast key searching on basis of binary data, Here is line which I am using to et actual key from IMap and using further to get value object.

```
HazelcastInstance instance = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance();
private static ConcurrentMap<HMapKey, String> testMap = instance.getMap("MY_HAZELCAST_MAP");
testMap.put(new HMapKey("code1",123), "This is Code 1");
....
....
....
// While retrieving
private static ConcurrentMap<HMapKey, String> testMap2 = instance.getMap("MY_HAZELCAST_MAP");
HMapKey key = new HMapKey("code1",0);
key = ArrayList<HMapKey>(testMap2.keySet()).get(new ArrayList<HMapKey>(testMap2.keySet()).indexOf(key));

String MapValue = testMap2.get(key);
```

Please let me know if I make you understand. Also I am connecting this question with my previous one. If this didn't work, will add that content in this question also.

Comment: If node 1 puts the data and node 2 gets back a null, this would suggest that node 1 and node 2 haven't joined together. Can you post their logs please ?

Comment: Data pushed almost a 30-40 min back and both nodes using it. But out of 10 calls, almost 2 to 3 time, I am getting `NULL` irrespective of nodes.

Comment: Plz post the complete hazelcast.xml and the code how you are trying to fetch the values. Also, if you can replicate this in a smaller testcase, it would help us.

Comment: Do you get the same behaviour if you turn off expiry ?  Try changing the config to `<map name="MY_HAZELCAST_MAP"/>`. As you have it currently configured the entries are removed after 1000 seconds -- this would explain retrievals getting null, but not later retrievals getting a value unless the value gets updated by another thread.

Comment: @Neil I have tried with removing that configuration, but no luck.

Comment: Can you post sample code demonstrating the problem please ?

Comment: What are you using as your key class ?

Comment: @Navnath This is probably the same issue as your earlier question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41238403/not-able-to-retrieve-element-from-hazelcasts-map-if-using-custom-object-as-a-ke . If the key's hash (not `hashCode()`) is not consistent then Hazelcast will look for it in different places, and so sometimes might find it and sometimes not. Can you post the current implementation of your `HMapKey` class please ? Try replacing `HMapKey` with a String in your put and get calls to confirm this. Then try using `HMapKey.toString()` as a String key to confirm again.

Comment: `HMapKey` is same which I have uploaded on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41238403/not-able-to-retrieve-element-from-hazelcasts-map-if-using-custom-object-as-a-ke question.

Comment: Your `HMapKey` is faulty. You have it defined currently with two non-transient fields, but the `equals()` method only tests one.

Comment: Yes. That's what My requirement. As that second variable may be differ. That's the reason while getting any element from Hazelcast Map First I am retrieving actual key and then going for value object. Please refer code which I have posted for same(lines are bellow comment "// While retrieving").

Comment: Your `HMapKey` is faulty. Keys must be unique. If the second field is not to be used in equality checking it should not be a part of the key.

Answer (score 0):

The key class `HMapKey` on [Not able to retrieve element from Hazelcast's Map if using custom object as a key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41238403/not-able-to-retrieve-element-from-hazelcasts-map-if-using-custom-object-as-a-ke) is what is causing the problem.

For a key, all fields should be part of equality testing.

Additionally for Hazelcast, keys are compared serialized.